# SEC_TO_TIME results incorrect

Tags: mysql

I ran the following SELECT statement on two different MySQL servers.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(7124718)
```

MySQL 5.1.69 returned 838:59:59 (incorrect)

MySQL 5.0.22 returned 1979:05:18 (correct)

I found documentation on the TIME data type for version 5.1 that mentions limits from -838:59:59 to 838:59:59

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html

The 5.0 documentation states the same limits on the TIME data type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're confused on.  The documentation properly addresses your question.  `838:59:59` is the upper bound of the `TIME` data type, as per the documentation.

Comment: What's your question? It is working in 5.1 the way it is supposed to work - large legal values are clipped to 838:59:59.

Comment: It states the same limit exists in 5.0, but the result I am getting on MySQL 5.0.22 is 1979:05:18

Comment: Why is MySQL 5.0.22 not limiting it to 838:59:59?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this was a bug (either in the implementation or documentation) in MySQL.  The bug report is [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11655).  It existed up until 4.1.23, **5.0.30**, and 5.1.13.  Up until those versions, `SEC_TO_TIME()` would not clip (limit to those aforementioned bounds).  In the changelogs, at these versions:

> Lack of validation for input and output TIME values resulted in
>   several problems: SEC_TO_TIME() within subqueries incorrectly clipped
>   large values; SEC_TO_TIME() treated BIGINT UNSIGNED values as signed;
>   only truncation warnings were produced when both truncation and
>   out-of-range TIME values occurred.

If you can, please use an up-to-date version of MySQL.  In addition to bug fixes, they also have security fixes which may be necessary for your system.